# Not able to run self-hosted sentry on CentOS

Tags: docker-compose, centos7, sentry, clickhouse

I am trying to install self-hosted sentry on CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)) according to this documentation - https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/.
But when I run `sudo ./install.sh` I get this error:

```
 Failed to connect to clickhouse:9000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 260, in connect
    return self._init_connection(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 226, in _init_connection
    self.socket = self._create_socket(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 202, in _create_socket
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Connection to Clickhouse cluster clickhouse:9000 failed (attempt 9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/snuba/snuba/clickhouse/native.py", line 81, in execute
    result: Sequence[Any] = conn.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 205, in execute
    self.connection.force_connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 180, in force_connect
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 279, in connect
    raise err
clickhouse_driver.errors.NetworkError: Code: 210. Name or service not known (clickhouse:9000)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/snuba/snuba/migrations/connect.py", line 30, in check_clickhouse_connections
    check_clickhouse(clickhouse)
  File "/usr/src/snuba/snuba/migrations/connect.py", line 49, in check_clickhouse
    ver = clickhouse.execute("SELECT version()")[0][0]
  File "/usr/src/snuba/snuba/clickhouse/native.py", line 96, in execute
    raise ClickhouseError(e.code, e.message) from e
snuba.clickhouse.errors.ClickhouseError: [210] Name or service not known (clickhouse:9000)
Failed to connect to clickhouse:9000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 260, in connect
    return self._init_connection(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 226, in _init_connection
    self.socket = self._create_socket(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 202, in _create_socket
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The error from `docker-compose logs clickhouse`:

```
clickhouse_1                                | Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml'.
clickhouse_1                                | Merging configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/docker_related_config.xml'.
clickhouse_1                                | Merging configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml'.
clickhouse_1                                | Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Exception: Failed to merge config with '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml': Access to file denied: /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
clickhouse_1                                |
clickhouse_1                                | 0. Poco::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0x105351b0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 1. ? @ 0xdefbd83 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 2. DB::ConfigProcessor::loadConfig(bool) @ 0xdef9e97 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 3. BaseDaemon::reloadConfiguration() @ 0x9157010 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 4. BaseDaemon::initialize(Poco::Util::Application&) @ 0x91597d2 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 5. DB::Server::initialize(Poco::Util::Application&) @ 0x8f96458 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 6. Poco::Util::Application::run() @ 0x10457659 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 7. DB::Server::run() @ 0x8f96045 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 8. mainEntryClickHouseServer(int, char**) @ 0x8f8ce23 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 9. main @ 0x8ee8799 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                | 10. __libc_start_main @ 0x21b97 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
clickhouse_1                                | 11. _start @ 0x8ee802e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
clickhouse_1                                |  (version 20.3.9.70 (official build))
clickhouse_1                                | Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml'.
clickhouse_1                                | Merging configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/docker_related_config.xml'.
clickhouse_1                                | Merging configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml'.
clickhouse_1                                | Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Exception: Failed to merge config with '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml': Access to file denied: /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
```

There is error - `Access to file denied: /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml` at clickhouse logs (similar issue - https://forum.sentry.io/t/click-house-giving-permission-errors/12418). How can I set correct permission for this file?

Comment: But your error is `Access to file denied: /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/sentry.xml` so this file can't be accessed by CH during startup, thus no successful start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by giving **777 permissions** for some folders of sentry installation. I know that it can be not desirable for someone but it is easy and fast solution.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./clickhouse
sudo chmod -R 777 ./relay
sudo chmod -R 777 ./sentry
sudo chmod -R 777 ./postgres
```

Comment: This is probably not the way you'd want to go, since this opens up a lot of security risks.

The files are now both readable AND writable by _anyone_ on the system. No root required.
`./sentry` contains secrets as well.

You probably want to figure out which user is running inside the container and make the files readable for that user.

Comment: At least do `chmod -R ugo+rX` so that (1) only read permissions are given, (2) only the correct files get the executable bit

Comment: Hi there! I am also trying to set up self hosted sentry, could you let me know what are the pros and cons for the same? Or how is it better than the hosted sentry ?